# Proving discontinuity of a function - I've nearly got it!

Tags: real-analysis

The function is $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)=0$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ else $f(x)=x$. (Classic real analysis function, these kind of things had me suffering withdraw symptoms from the "Eulerian" functions of A-level)

I can show it is continuous at $x=0$ quite easily. Well very easily! I can almost show it is discontinuous at $x\ne 0$, that is (for discontinuity at $c$)

$\exists \epsilon>0\forall\delta>0\exists x\text{ with }|x-c|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(c)|\ge\epsilon$

So, let $c\ne0$ be given, if $c\in\mathbb{Q}$ then notice we can choose an $x$ **really close** to $c$ where $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$ so that $|f(x)-f(c)|=|f(x)|$ with an $x$ really close to $c$

OR if $c\notin\mathbb{Q}$ then notice we can choose $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ for any $\delta$ and get $|f(x)-f(c)|=|f(c)|$

I now need to choose an $\epsilon$, anything $<|c|$ ought to do

But I'm struggling on writing it.

### Might have just got it:

$|x-a|<\delta\implies -\delta<x-a<\delta\implies-\delta+a<x<\delta+a$

Wait... well this gives me an $x$ and as it must work for all $\delta$ ... I'm close!

Comment: Use sequential continuity. A function from an interval into the real numbers is continuous at a point $x$ if and only if for every sequence {$x_n$} (in the interval) such that $x_n\rightarrow x$ converges to $x$, we have that the sequence {$f(x_n)$} converges to $f(x)$.

Comment: @Cass I could but I should be able to this way. This is what the question is about after all!

Comment: Yes, but it tends to be easier to deal with sequential limits then to deal with delta epsilons.

Comment: @Cass that's not in the spirit of the question.

Comment: How is it not? It's not your method, but it's the more concise proof, and the principle is the same. In fact the principle is illustrated more clearly.

Comment: @Cass What do you mean how is it not? The question comes from a context silly! I could solve it another way, but I *ought* to be able to solve it this way.

Comment: Is it necessary to call names? You should be able to solve it your way, but there's no reason to. The mathematics of my method is on the same level, the concept of my method is the same, the only difference is that my method is neater and more concise.

Comment: @Cass when someone needs bus times do you brag about having a car?

Comment: I'm trying to show you the most efficient way to solve the problem with standard techniques from the course you're presumably taking. Shall I apologize for that?

Comment: @Cass but I know about sequential continuity, I'm revising and *this* is what I'm stuck with

Comment: @AlecTeal The equivalence of sequential continuity and epsilon-delta continuity is so elementary that any proof in one definition can be translated into a proof in the other definition with zero effort (if you don't agree, you should try revising exactly this). I am dismayed that you are giving Cass such a hard time, when he/she is giving constructive input.

Comment: @JoshuaPepper I do not see why. I am revising something. I cannot do something a certain way and have asked for help doing it a certain way. I ought to be able to do this the way described. I don't thing comments on sequential continuity should have dragged on this far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for any $a\neq0$ choose $\epsilon=\dfrac{|a|}{2} $ then for all $\delta>0$ we need to find $x$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ but $\epsilon\leq|f(x)-f(a)|$.

**case$1$:** If $a\in Q$;

then clearly $f(a)=0$ then let $x$ be an irrational number in $(a,a+\delta)$ , then $|x|>\dfrac{|a|}{2}$ so $$|f(x)-f(a)|=|x|>\epsilon $$

**correction:** if $a<0$ choose $x$ from $(a-\delta,a)$for above argument.

**case$2$:** if $a\notin Q;$

then $f(a)=a$ then let $x$ be an rational number in $(a,a+\delta)$, then

$$|f(x)-f(a)|=|a|>\epsilon$$

**Notes:** Notice that all open interval inludes infinitly many rationals and irrational numbers so we can always find such a $x$ for all $\delta$.

Comment: I don't see how $|x|>\frac{|a|}{2}$ (and thus epsilon) .... OH! You chose from the far half! I knew I was close (am I just telling myself this?)!

Comment: @AlecTeal: you were close :)

Comment: Just quickly, (I chose to leave the question and come back, that way I can use your method but not your answer (it isn't fresh in my mind)) Why did you pick $\frac{|a|}{2}$ I have shown $|f(x)-f(c)|\ge|c|$ in any case. (there were 3, $c\in\mathbb{Q}$ and the two cases of sign for $c\notin\mathbb{Q}$) so I could pick $\epsilon=|c| surely? I know there's no unique $\epsilon$ but why half? First number that comes to mind for a number between 0 and 1? Avoiding the =1 case entirely?

Comment: @AlecTeal : you can also choose $\epsilon=|c|$. I had showed that $|f(x)-f(c)|$ is stricly greater than $\epsilon$. But we do not need this it is enough to show that $|f(x)-f(c)|\ge \epsilon$ as you did.

Answer (score 2):

It will suffice to show that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ doesn't exists for $a\not =0$. Suppose to the contrary that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$.

Let $\varepsilon=|a|/4$ so there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$. Let $0<|x-a|<\min\left(\delta, |a|/2\right)$. From the last inequality it follows that $|x|>|a|/2$. If $x$ is irrational $|x-L|<\varepsilon$ and if $y$ is rational $|L|<\varepsilon$. Suppose that $x$ is irrational. Then

$$\frac{|a|}{2}<|x|=|x-L+L|\le |x-L|+|L|<2\varepsilon=\frac{|a|}{2}$$

a contradiction.